# Spring Boot + Thymeleaf + Apache tiles - cannot find a definition file

Tags: java, configuration, spring-boot, thymeleaf, apache-tiles

I have a weird problem with my configuration. I'm trying to configure apache tiles with thymeleaf. I'm trying to do the same things they are on theirs [documentation page](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html#thymeleaf-tiles-integration).

I have following configuration file:

```
@Configuration
public class ViewConfig {

@Bean
public ViewResolver tilesViewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver vr = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    vr.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    vr.setViewClass(ThymeleafTilesView.class);
    vr.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    vr.setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return vr;
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver vr = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    vr.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    vr.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    vr.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    // all message/* views will not be handled by this resolver;
    vr.setExcludedViewNames(new String[]{"message/*"});
    return vr;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.addDialect(new TilesDialect());
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    return templateEngine;
}

@Bean
public ThymeleafTilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
    ThymeleafTilesConfigurer ttc = new ThymeleafTilesConfigurer();
    ttc.setValidateDefinitions(false);
    ttc.setDefinitions(new String[]{"/templates/tiles-defs.xml"});
    return ttc;
}

@Bean
public TemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setPrefix("templates/");
    resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    return resolver;
}

}
```

I've added TemplateResolver for my purposes, but removing it doesn't help (for having the same configuration as documentation).
This is my resource folder structure:
[image]

And the problem is that I've got following exception:
`Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/templates/tiles-defs.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist`
The most interesting is that I've checked `target/classes` (which is in classpath) and there is the file `templates/tiles-defs.xml`.
I've tried a couple of times to change the definition path (also I've tried to remove definition and get it from default `WEB-INF/tiles.xml` path) but no outcome - same exception.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it:

```
@Bean
public ThymeleafTilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
    ThymeleafTilesConfigurer ttc = new ThymeleafTilesConfigurer();
    //ttc.setValidateDefinitions(false);
    ttc.setDefinitions(ThymeleafProperties.DEFAULT_PREFIX + "tiles-defs.xml");
    return ttc;
}
```